# UITest interruption handler calling tap() twice

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

My UITest requires a button to be tapped and the UIInteruptionMonitor should handle it. However, what happens is the button gets tapped, the interruption appears and gets handled and then it tries to tap the button again. It seems to think it hasn't actually tapped the button when it has...

I have the following code:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Permissions") { alert -> Bool in
    let okButton = alert.buttons["OK"]
    if okButton.exists {
      okButton.tap()
    }

    return true
}

app.buttons["Enable"].tap()
```

What happens is the following:

```
t =    91.24s     Find the "Enable" Button
    t =    91.40s     Check for interrupting elements affecting "Enable" Button
    t =    91.42s         Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
    t =    91.85s     Found 1 interrupting element:
    t =    91.86s         Find the "“MyApp” Would Like to Access the Camera" Alert
    t =    92.03s         "“MyApp” Would Like to Access the Camera" Alert from Application 'com.apple.springboard'
    t =    92.03s     Invoking UI interruption monitors for "“MyApp” Would Like to Access the Camera" Alert from Application 'com.apple.springboard'
    t =    92.03s         Invoking Permissions
    t =    92.04s             Checking existence of `"OK" Button`
    t =    92.21s             Tap "OK" Button
    t =    92.21s                 Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
    t =    92.50s                 Find the "OK" Button
    t =    92.66s                 Check for interrupting elements affecting "OK" Button
    t =    92.82s                 Synthesize event
    t =    93.14s                 Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
    t =    93.54s         Verifying handling...
    t =    93.54s             Check for interrupting elements affecting "Enable" Button
    t =    93.55s                 Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
    t =    94.10s         Confirmed successful handling of interrupting element
    t =    94.10s     Synthesize event
    t =    95.39s         Scroll element to visible
    t =    96.55s         Failed: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button, label: 'Enable', error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 62934, elementOrHash.elementID: 140664883255456.613
    t =    97.57s     Retrying `Tap "Enable" Button` (attempt #2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. When interrupted by a system alert, the intended action could not be performed, so it is retried after successful handling of the interruption.

More generally, you must check within the handler if you dealt with the interruption successfully (e.g. you found the ok button and could tap it), otherwise, you must return false.